# Replace any single digit value to NA in a column without affecting 2 digit or more than 2 digits

Tags: r

I have 100 observations and 15 variables as my data set in that one column contains both digit and alphabets.

I want to replace only the single digit present in the data points

For example:

```
Donor
345abc
3
0
789edf
101er
```

Expected Output:

```
Donor
345abc
NA
NA
789edf
101er
```

---

```
dt$column=[dt$column==3]<-NA

dt$column=[dt$column==0]<-NA
```

I used above lines as temporary solution but I rewrite this code (0 - 9) how to use regex or gsub in this situation to write one line code

Answer (score 1):

```
df$column_name <- with(df, gsub("^\\d$",NA,column_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
dt$column[nchar(dt$column)==1 & nchar(gsub('[[:digit:]]', '', dt$column))==0]=NA
```

If the string is a single character, and after replacing the digits it is zero characters long, replace the value with NA.

EXAMPLE

```
dt = data.frame(column=c(1,"dog",2,"bike"))
dt$column  = as.character(dt$column)

  column
1      1
2    dog
3      2
4   bike
```

becomes

```
  column
1   <NA>
2    dog
3   <NA>
4   bike
```

> EDIT: Example 2 based on comments

```
> dt
  column
1 3.1dog
2  5bike
3      1
4      2
5   EL0O

> dt$column[nchar(dt$column)==1 & nchar(gsub('[[:digit:]]', '', dt$column))==0]=NA

> dt
  column
1 3.1dog
2  5bike
3   <NA>
4   <NA>
5   EL0O
```

Comment: My Data point contains c(3.1dog , 5bike ,1,2,EL0O,) so I cant use gsub('[[:digit:]]' which will delete all my digit

Comment: No, that is not how my code works. It checks if the number of characters of the string is 1, AND if the number of characters of the string is 0 after all digits have been replaced. I have added your example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the 'column' to `numeric`, get the index of non-NA values and assign it to NA

```
dt$column[!is.na(as.numeric(dt$column)) &  nchar(dt$column)==1] <- NA
dt  
#   column
#1 345abc
#2   <NA>
#3   <NA>
#4 789edf
#5  101er
```

#### data

```
dt <- structure(list(column = c("345abc", "3", "0", "789edf", "101er"
 )), .Names = "column", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: "I want to replace only the single digit present in the data points"